# firebase is not defined- JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

Empecé con firebase recién y quise probar un código de ejemplo de otro usuario y me funciona con sus datos pero cuando lo adapto con los datos que firebase me da para mi app web no funciona. El código original es este https://mega.nz/#F!TxZR0CiR!D3zer79C--_nvZTir7_FVg

No encuentro el problema ya que sólo estoy reemplazando sus datos por los míos(cambié ya los valores en las reglas de la base de datos de "false" a "true" ).

Es para agregar nuevas tareas a la base de datos con un nombre y una descripción y la fecha y luego se muestran en una tabla, todo funciona perfectamente pero al poner mis datos no muestra nada y tampoco guarda nada. 
Los únicos datos que cambié son los dos primeros scripts del index.html, en firebase.js reemplacé mis datos y eso solo.

y acá el código:

en el index.html:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Example - Firebase</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="nav justify-content-end bg-dark">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <h2 class="nav-link active white">Firebase</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="text-left">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTask">
                        Add Task
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <input type="text" id="search" class="inpSearch" placeholder="Search Data">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered text-center">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Creation</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="loadTable"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="text-left">
                                <h5>Edit Task</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="onClickUpdate()" id="update">Update</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="editData"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalTask" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTask" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTask">Insert Task</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea placeholder="Description" class="form-control" id="desc"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="onClickInsert()">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>





    <script src="firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="logic.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-eVEQC9zshBn0rFj4+TU78eNA19HMNigMviK/PU/FFjLXqa/GKPgX58rvt5Z8PLs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

en firebase.js:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-",
    authDomain: "-",
    databaseURL: "-",
    projectId: "-",
    storageBucket: "-",
    messagingSenderId: "-",
    appId: "-",

  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
```

y en logic.js:

```
var db = firebase.database();

var update = document.getElementById('update');
update.disabled = true;

function value(request){
    return  document.getElementById(request).value;
}
function asignation(request,response){
    return  document.getElementById(request).value=response;
}
function printHTML(request,response){
    return document.getElementById(request).innerHTML+=response;
}
function inHTML(request,response){
    return document.getElementById(request).innerHTML=response;
}
function dateActuality(){
    var fh = new Date();
    return fh.getFullYear()+"-"+(fh.getMonth()+1)+"-"+fh.getDate()+" "+fh.getHours()+":"+fh.getMinutes();
}
function insertTask(name,description){
    db.ref('task/').push({
        name:name,
        description:description,
        date:dateActuality()
    });
}
function onClickInsert(){
    var name = value("name");
    var description = value("desc");
    if(name.length==0 || description.length==0){ 
        alert("empty field"); 
    }else{ 
        inHTML("loadTable","");
        insertTask(name,description); 
        asignation("name","");
        asignation("desc","");
        alert("saved successfully");
    }
}
function updateTask(name,description,key){
    db.ref('task/'+key).update({
        name:name,
        description:description,
        date:dateActuality()
    });
}
function onClickUpdate(){
    var name = value("nameEdit");
    var description = value("descEdit");
    var key = value("key"); 
    if(name.length==0 || description.length==0){ 
        alert("empty field"); 
    }else{ 
        inHTML("loadTable","");
        updateTask(name,description,key); 
        inHTML("editData","");
        alert("modify successfully");
        update.disabled = true;
    }
}
function removeTask(key){
    if(confirm("¿you want to delete task?")){
        inHTML("loadTable","");
        db.ref('task/'+key).remove();
    }
}
function table(name,description,date,key){
    return '<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+description+'</td><td>'+date+'</td>'+
    '<td><a href="#" onclick="viewDataUpdate(\''+name+'\',\''+description+'\',\''+key+'\')">'+
    '<i class="fas fa-edit blue icon-lg"></i></a></td>'+
    '<td><a href="#" onclick="removeTask(\''+key+'\')">'+
     '<i class="fas fa-trash-alt red icon-lg"></i></a></td></tr>';
}
function viewDataUpdate(name,description,key){
    var response = '<div class="form-group"><input type="hidden" value='+key+' id="key">' +
    '<input type="text" id="nameEdit" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value='+name+'>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="form-group">'+
    '<textarea placeholder="DescriptionEdit" class="form-control" id="descEdit">'+description+'</textarea>'+
    '</div>';
    inHTML('editData',response);
    update.disabled = false;
}
var reference = db.ref('task/');    
reference.on('value',function(datas){
    var data = datas.val();
    $.each(data, function(nodo, value) {
            var sendData = table(value.name,value.description,value.date,nodo);
            printHTML('loadTable',sendData);
    });       
});
```

Comment: En `firebaseConfig` tienes que poner tus propias credenciales, las cuales, supongo, ya obtuviste en la consola de desarrolladores de Google y que también activaste la API de Firebase. Además, convendría que en dicha consola autorices peticiones desde tu dominio. Cuéntanos lo que has hecho en ese sentido.

Comment: gracias por responder, en la consola cambie las reglas para read y write , de false puse a true... eso es todo lo que hice ademas de crear obviamente un proyecto con su realtime database y una app web dentro del mismo(use los datos de firebaseconfig que me proporciona google pero todavía no encuentro el error ). Debo descargar alguna api de firebase y agregarla a mis archivos? solo uso este codigo: firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);